# How to individually set the width of a row on a table/scrollpane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, defaulttablemodel

i have a DefaultTableModel:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, beschriftung)
        {
            //  Returning the Class of each column will allow different
            //  renderers to be used based on Class
            public Class getColumnClass(int column)
            {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }
        };
```

This is inside a table:

```
JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.setEnabled(false);
        table.setRowHeight(50);
```

And the table is inside a scrollPane:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollPane.setBounds(1215, 11, 300, 300);
        scrollPane.setWheelScrollingEnabled(true);
        scrollPane.setEnabled(false);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
```

I have two rows, but want the first one to be shorter than the second one. Any suggestions?

This is how it looks like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQQsz.png]

This is how I want it to look like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/28UTf.png]

Comment: The width of the table is defined by the number of columns in the model. Each row will contain the same number of columns. You could have it so that one row displays no data in the columns but the grid lines will still be painted for each column. So you can't make one row appear shorter than the other. You could have one row with a different height. Read the JTable API. There is a method to set the height of an individual row. Also don't use setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. The layout manager will then set the size/location of the component

Comment: sorry, but could you look at the two pictures I sent? is it really not possible to open it like that, even if I can scroll it like that?

Comment: So you want the width of each "column" to be different than the other, not the row.

Comment: if you say so, sorrry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out:

1. Check of the section from the Swing tutorial on [Setting and Changing Columns Widths](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#width). It shows how you can manually set a preferred size for each column.

The basic code would be:

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(???).setPreferredWidth(???)
```

2. You can also check out the [Table Column Adjuster](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/) for automatic sizing of columns based on the data contained in the model

The basic code for this approach is:

```
JTable table = new JTable( ... );
table.setAutoResizeMode( JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF );
 
for (int column = 0; column < table.getColumnCount(); column++)
{
    TableColumn tableColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column);
    int preferredWidth = tableColumn.getMinWidth();
    int maxWidth = tableColumn.getMaxWidth();
 
    for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++)
    {
        TableCellRenderer cellRenderer = table.getCellRenderer(row, column);
        Component c = table.prepareRenderer(cellRenderer, row, column);
        int width = c.getPreferredSize().width + table.getIntercellSpacing().width;
        preferredWidth = Math.max(preferredWidth, width);
 
        //  We've exceeded the maximum width, no need to check other rows
 
        if (preferredWidth >= maxWidth)
        {
            preferredWidth = maxWidth;
            break;
        }
    }
 
    tableColumn.setPreferredWidth( preferredWidth );
}
```

The `TableColumnAdjuster` class in the link contains other features as well.

Also check out the JTable API for the `setAutoResizeMode(...)` method to determine how space is allocated if the width of the table changes.

Comment: One last question: Is it possible to only automatically size the first column with the pictures and let the second column fill the remaining space?

Comment: Already answered. See the last sentence. I would set the resize mode after the preferred sizes have been set.